Informative Puzzle
What word describes the image below? Explain your reasoning.



Hint 1

 Nicknames in the same "C".


Ignore the different shadings and sizes of the cross, not important (haven't had access to laptop lately, so not easy to edit images etc).


 The word here is NEWS


 Let’s look at the words from left to right up and down. The first thing to notice is that They are part of nicknames of cities in the USA.

We have

 BIG APPLE, DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA, EL CHUCO and EMERALD CITY.

If we

 look at the formal names of these city nicknames we get NEW YORK, WASHINGTON, EL PASO and SEATTLE.


 Taking the first letters of each of these we get the four main compass directions N,W,E,S which also correspond to the positions the words have in relation to one another.

What about the x’s

 So the X means times as in ‘multiply’. So we have the New York Times, El Paso times etc…

and what are these

 They are the news and if you take the compass directions you can spell this out to make the answer. This fits with with the title since the news is certainly informative


Well done so far! But this is not the final answer. In order to find the final answer you have to make sense of the "cross" too. What could it possibly mean?

Is this better now?

No not the answer. Think of a specific common word associated with the cross. It's not intended to be read as the letter x. Once you find the word it all will make sense.

Sorry but this isn't it either. The answer doesn't even contain the word "directions". Hopefully this will help... the "x's" in the puzzle don't exactly look like the letter x.

How about now? I think this is correct

You got what the "x" stands for now, but what is another word for multiply? Like if you read 1×1 what word did you use for the "×"?

I was thinking a clock because of times before but I don’t know if this is the idea

Is this answer?

Now it looks good, that's the answer . Nice job!

I propose the word:

 HEADING

As PDT pointed out, the words refer to:

 The cities of Washington, New York, Seattle, and El Paso; whose initial letters refer to the cardinal directions.

In addition,

 The 'x' symbol is read as "times" giving us the names of newspapers: "New York Times", "Seattle Times", etc.

I conclude:

 The word HEADING fits because it can be used in both a journalistic context, referring to the headline of a newspaper, and a navigational context, based on cardinal directions.



 The word is Railway

Similar to what PDT posted, except:

 The crosses shown in the picture represent railroad crossing signs. Also, a synonym for direction (i.e. N,S,E,W) is way. Hence, we end up with Railway.


Same logic leads to "crossroad".

No this is not it. It has nothing to do with railway
